# Diode N value less than 1 for temperature sweep

Tags: diodes, simulation, ltspice, pspice, modeling

I have seen many manufactures using diodes N<1 for their PSpice model and LTSpice model diodes so I tried to run temperature sweep in LTSpice and PSpice

- In LTSpice if N<1 DC sweep eg:1m with .temp it dont provide necessary plot
  [image: Temperature Sweep]

For Pspice

[image: Schematic]

> .MODEL DB D(N=1m)

with Temperature other than 27C we get error

[image: Error]

- So I tried to keep N=1036 and tried to match IS accordingly in EXCEL but the overlayed result diode current dont match for N=1m
  [image]
- Is there any other way to match diode drop and current in PSpice of N=1m, So that it can be temperature swept?

Comment: `N` is usually `1...2,3` or so, and `Is` ranges from femto to micro, or nano, so what you have there may be an abomination. It might be time to step back a bit and rethink.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding LTspice, you cannot simultaneously use a `.TEMP` and a `.STEP` command .

`.TEMP` is an archaic form of the step command for temperature. It is equivalent to

```
.STEP TEMP LIST <T1> <T2> ...
```

which reveals why adding another `.STEP` command yields no simulation.

Just use e.g. a transient analysis, like

```
.tran 1m
.step temp list 0 20 40 60 80 100
OR
.temp 0 20 40 60 80 100
```

to step the temperature.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it but is it possible to match  N=1m (in PSpice) behavior by above methods which I mentioned i have to carry it out by 1] Spice diode statement [2] Macro--Model Sub circuit ?(*As I mentioned N=1m notifies overflow of the device)